# Update database information with onClick function

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to update a tables row **site_active** in mysql using an onClick function with a button.

My button code is:

```
<button onClick='site_active()' id='site_active'><?php echo $client->site_active; ?></button>
```

And then of course my Script is:

```
<script> 
   function site_active() 
   {
      alert("Site Updated"); 
   } 
</script>
```

I am sure that I need to use a php function to make this happen and I have the following code from my attempt to just do it with a form.

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("INFORMATION REMOVED"); 
//Check connnection 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ 
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
} 

mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mypanda_clients SET site_active='$_GET[site_active]' WHERE id='$_GET[id]'"); 

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

The form option did not work because of some clashing problems in the website. ANY help would be great as I have spent hours on this with no progress. Thank You.

Comment: You can use AJAX in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use jquery and do an ajax request to the server

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
  //ajax request to the server goes here
});
```

Here the link for ajax in jquery
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/